# batch script delete file when file name matches pattern

Tags: batch-file

Quite nervous today, I am a long time StackOverflow voyeur about to ask my first ever question so I hope I dont suck at it. I can perform the following task easily using something like a console app but i was hoping that it would be possible to do it in a batch script, and I dont know batch scripting well at all.

I want to delete all files in a directory except those whose name matches a certain pattern.  A typical example of the kind of files in this directory is as follows:

- dep_invoice_101.pdf -- *to delete*
- dep_invoice_102.pdf -- *to delete*
- invoice_103.pdf -- *to delete*
- invoice_106.pdf -- *to delete*
- invoice_106_E56.pdf -- **keep**
- deposit_invoice_101_068.pdf -- **keep**

i want to delete all files except those whose name matches

- any string (or nothing) followed by "invoice_"
- followed by any number
- then an underscore
- then another alphanumeric string

The final underscore is the key.  if i was doing this using C# or something, i would extract the name into a string, remove all text before "invoice_" and then see if there is a remaining underscore - this would be a match, e.g.

- "deposit_invoice_101_068.pdf"
- search for "invoice_" and remove all text before and including this
- left with "101_068.pdf"
- if there are any underscores in this string then it is a match

Hope this makes sense.  If this is not an appropriate question let me know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 SET "filename=!filename:*invoice_=!"
 IF "!filename!"=="!filename:_=!" ECHO DEL "%sourcedir%\%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

You'd need to change your `sourcedir` to suit, naturally.

This follows your `how I'd do it in C` rather than your narrative spec.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'dir /a-d /b *.pdf ^| findstr /v /r /c:"invoice_[0-9][0-9]*_.*\.pdf$"'
) do echo del "%%a"
```

If output to console is correct, remove the `echo` command